# How do I start a service when I receive an intent?

Tags: android, service, android-service

I'm making a [wearable plugin](https://www.docs.sleep.urbandroid.org/devs/wearable_api.html) for Sleep as Android. It uses an intent-based API, eg upon receiving `com.urbandroid.sleep.watch.START_TRACKING`, every 2 minutes the app is supposed to send an intent with the collected data. However I can't figure out a way to keep sending the data in the background.

If I just send the data from the BroadcastReceiver, it gets killed eventually. If the app isn't in the background and tries to start a service, I get an error (its content varies, but it's something about how apps in the background can't start services).

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the possibility that your Service could be killed by the OS....there isn't any possibility to avoid/bypass this: your Service COULD be killed without any exception.
When managed this, you can dedicate ad empty/transparent/hidden Activity that will be executed/started and which starts the BackgroundService before executes its "Activity.finish()" to be closed meanwhile the Service continues to work behind the scenes.
Don't forget to call special methods like "startForegroundService()" or the Service will live just 5 seconds before been killed by OS.